# Derivation of the naive bootstrap variance estimator

Tags: bootstrap

I am learning the bootstrap method, and reading Rao and Wu's (1988) classic paper "Resampling Inference with Complex Survey Data." On the section of "The Naive Bootstrap" (as the picture shown below), I found that I don't know how to derive Equation 2.3. I feel that that equation is fundamental to the so-called "Rao-Wu rescaled bootstrap", so I would like to know how to derive it step by step.

[image]